# UpdatePanel in webpart - title in browser tab disappears

Tags: web-part, updatepanel

I created a webpart with standard asp.net Update Panel. I noticed, that as soon as content of that UpdatePanel gets reloaded, title in browser tab disappears (or changes to `http://servername`, depending on a browser).

I don't understand that behavior. My question:

1. why does title disappear?
2. how can I avoid that? (programatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this blog post:
http://softlanding.ca/blog/page-title-disappearing-after-ajax-postbacks, that explained, how to fix the problem (in short, placeholder in masterpage must be all single line).

Still, this seems a strange bug. Can someone explain, why this happens?